# Beat Detection from line in

Tags: java, audio, fft, heartbeat

I wan't to try some beat detection algorithms from [here](http://archive.gamedev.net/reference/programming/features/beatdetection/) in Java. My problem: How do I get the current audio mix from the soundcard as datasource for the algorithms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Java Tutorial for [Accessing Audio System Resources](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html).